# What is the difference between Hexagonal Architecture and Anti Corruption Layer Pattern?

Tags: architecture, architectural-patterns, hexagonal-architecture

I tried searching the web but can't understand the difference/boundary between hexagonal(ports and adapter) architecture and ACL Pattern.
While hexagonal architecture talks about creating ports(interfaces) and adapters(implementation), doesn't ACL also do same by adding a layer which is corruption free and isn't impacted by any upstream or downstream system change?

Comment: "anti-corruption layer" isn't an architecture, it's just a fancy phrase to describe decoupling your own code away from some other code which is outside of your control.      More importantly (and to address the premise of the question), there are no formal definitions of these terms;  they are merely phrases which various different authors have described in books at different times.  Authors have no more authority than anybody else when it comes to defining language or deciding how language is used.   It's very unlikely that the people who invented these terms had ever spoken to each other.

Comment: @BenCottrell So, what we do in Hexagonal architecture is ACL? So adapters in "ports and adapter" is actually an ACL ?

Comment: @BenCottrell yes, in a certain way, because ACL is not self sufficient to define the full architecture of a system. But depending on the [definition of architecture](https://martinfowler.com/architecture/) usesd, ACL qualiffies as an architectural matter. It is an important pattern defined by Evans that significantly impacts the design and the structure of the system and its robustness over the long term. Moreover it is difficult to add or remove afterward.  So it seems to check a lot of boxes of a lot of architecture definitions. Can we agree on architectural pattern ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are orthogonal architectures:

- The anticorruption layer is an architectural pattern that intends to isolate one bounded context from the modifications of another bounded context, at the domain design level.
- The hexagonal architecture does not prescribe anything about domain design, and just provides a way, using dependency injection, to isolate the core of an application from the rest of the world using the ports to isolate the services needed and provided, thus facilitating interchangeability.

The key point here, is that ACL  does not imply a traditional layered architecture (see this
[other question about layered and hexagonal architectures](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/436194/209774)), but is about domain objects and their interface, and hexagonal architecture is not about domain objects but about organizing the interfaces with outside.

You can therefore combine the two, using DI to define the ACL objects/services, and plug them via a port to another service implementing the other domain.